# How to determine the friction constants

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, friction

We know that the friction is formulated in this form $$F=av+bv^2+Nμ$$ I'm working with an object and surface and I want to find $ a, b, μ $ for them.

Can you please give me an experimental method ?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of methods that is widely used.

1. incline plane method
2. horizontal plane method

There is a very good expriment suggested by Pellissippi State Community collage
Below is the link that defines what and how to do it. Check out the below link

http://www.pstcc.edu/departments/natural_behavioral_sciences/Web%20Physics/Experiment%2006%20PHYS%201310.htm

Comment: I said finding  a,b,μ not just μ.

Answer (score 0):

Measure F at 3 (or more) different velocities and curve fit a parabola to the data.